# Datepicker in .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the code i have tried to install the date picker inside a table but i have no idea how to insert .pls anyone help me to rectify the issue.
To be inserted to this tbl

```
<table id="TblDate" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td width="50Px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td width="150Px">
          //here i want the date picker

        </td>
        <td width="40Px">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
        </td>


    </tr>
</table>
```

**Code:**

```
<div align='center'>
        Select Date: <input type='text' id='sel' onclick='dispCal()' size=10 readonly='readonly' />
    <img src='img/calendar.png' onclick='dispCal()' style='cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle;' />
        <table class='calendar' id='calendar' border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr class='monthdisp'>
                <td class='navigate' align='left'><img src='img/previous.png' onclick='return prev()' /></td>
                <td align='center' id='month'></td>
                <td class='navigate' align='right'><img src='img/next.png' onclick='return next()' /></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=3>
                    <table id='dispDays' border=0 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=4>                        
                    </table>                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a ASP.Net webforms you can use [AjaxControlToolkit calendar](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).

But you can use a [JqueryUI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) too.